# Problem with backticks in shellscript

Tags: shell, backticks

I am having a problem getting my shellscript working using backticks.  Here is an example version of the script I am having an issue with:

```
#!/bin/sh

ECHO_TEXT="Echo this"
ECHO_CMD="echo ${ECHO_TEXT} | awk -F' ' '{print \$1}'"

result=`${ECHO_CMD}`;
echo $result;

result=`echo ${ECHO_TEXT} | awk -F' ' '{print \$1}'`;
echo $result;
```

The output of this script is:

```
sh-3.2$ ./test.sh 
Echo this | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'
Echo
```

Why does the first backtick using a variable for the command not actually execute the full command but only returns the output of the first command along with the second command?  I am missing something in order to get the first backtick to execute the command?

Comment: Backticks are horribly outdated and should not be used any more -- using `$()` instead will save you many headaches

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (don't put commands in variables) and [BashFAQ/048](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) (avoid using `eval`). Also, your shebang says "#!/bin/sh" and your prompt says "sh", but your question tag says `[bash]` which is not the same thing.

Comment: I didn't set the bash tag, another user changed that after I posted this.

Comment: POSIX sh supports `$()`. There is no excuse.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use `eval` to get it working

```
result=`eval ${ECHO_CMD}`;
```

in place of

```
result=`${ECHO_CMD}`;
```

Without `eval`

```
${ECHO_TEXT} | awk -F' ' '{print \$1}
```

which will be expanded to

```
Echo this | awk -F' ' '{print \$1}
```

will be treated as argument to `echo` and will be output verbatim. With `eval` that line will actually be *run*.

Answer (score 2):

You Hi,

you need to know *eval* command.

See :

```
#!/bin/sh

ECHO_TEXT="Echo this"
ECHO_CMD="echo ${ECHO_TEXT} | awk -F' ' '{print \$1}'"

result="`eval ${ECHO_CMD}`"
echo "$result"

result="`echo ${ECHO_TEXT} | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`"
echo "$result"
```

Take a look to the doc :

```
help eval
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example echo is parsing the parameters - the shell never sees them.  In the second example it works because the shell is doing the parsing and knows what to do with a pipe.  If you change ECHO_CMD to be "bash echo ..." it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Bash is escaping your command for you.  Try

```
ECHO_TEXT="Echo this"
ECHO_CMD='echo ${ECHO_TEXT} | awk -F" " "'"{print \$1}"'"'

result=`${ECHO_CMD}`;
echo $result;

result=`echo ${ECHO_TEXT} | awk -F' ' '{print \$1}'`;
echo $result;
```

Or even better, try set -x on the first line, so you see what bash is doing