# Using backtick expression with variable embedded in an rcp command

Tags: sh, eval, rcp, backticks

I need to use a variable within a backtick expression embedded in a `rcp` invocation.

My initial attempt:

```
#!/bin/sh
release=1
rcp myserver.foo.com:'`ls -t /path/to/my/${release} | head -n 1`' .
```

I suppose this is failing because the back-tick expression is being executed on `myserver.foo.com` which doesn't have a `release` variable, so the argument to my `ls` command is just `/path/to/my/`.

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927062/problem-with-backticks-in-shellscript) that typically the `eval` command can be used to (I think) pre-process the back-tick expression. When I try that approach:

```
#!/bin/sh
release=1
rcp myserver.foo.com:'`ls -t /path/to/my/eval ${release} | head -n 1`' .
```

...the backtick expression is just executed as `/path/to/my/eval`.

How I can use variables in my backtick expression in this context?

To be clear: I'm attempting to have the code in back-ticks run on the remote server, not locally (but I need `${release}` to be resolved locally before-hand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the ls on the remote, but expand $release to its value on the local machine, you need to use different quotes.  To make the variable $release be exanded locally, it needs to be in double quotes, rather than single.  You can accomplish that with:

```
#!/bin/sh
release=1
scp myserver.foo.com:'$(ls -t /path/to/my/'"${release}"' | sed 1q)' .
```

If there are unusual characters (eg, whitespace) in the file names, you will probably want to add more quotes:

```
scp myserver.foo.com:'"$(ls -t /path/to/my/'"${release}"' | sed 1q)"' .
```

Note that you probably want to add the full path:

```
scp myserver.foo.com:/path/to/my/"$release"/'"$(ls -t /path/to/my/'"${release}"' | sed 1q)"' .
```

Comment: Thanks, but does the first `$` need to be escaped (`\$`)? It worked after I escaped it...

Comment: The first `$` should not need to be escaped.

Comment: It seems that the solutions you posted are causing the previously back-ticked command to be run locally, rather than on `myserver.foo.com`. But if I escape the `$` character it works...so thanks! You got me past my hurdle!

Comment: It's a little misleading to simply say to change the "spelling"...I understand that rcp should be considered legacy next to scp, but that is the technology that happen to be using in this scenerio...

Comment: Also a question...(probably a noob question), is there a reason why `sed` would be considered superior to using  `head` in this case?

Comment: No reason to prefer sed, it's just a personal preference.  Yes, the process substitution runs on the local machine.  By escaping the `$`, you are causing it to run on the remote (unless you include the embedded single quotes!)  To run on the remote, it's probably easier to do `rcp myserver.foo.com:'"$( ls -t /path/to/my'$release'| head -n 1)"'`

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Yes, I was trying to have the back-tick expression run on the remote server (that may not have been clear from my original question, which I have updated). If you update your answer to reflect this change, I'll test it and mark your answer as correct. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Updated to invoke ls on the remote.